# TypeError unhashable type: 'dict' using $elemMatch in count or find in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, find

The Users collection in the Mongo database contains records containing an element that is an array (SubscriptionSet) of dictionaries with pairs of values as shown below.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "567019357a5c390d040cbbc2"
    },
    "EmailAddress": "joejane@myco.com",
    "SubscriptionSet": [
        {
            "SubscriptionId": 586102,
            "SeatState": "ASSIGNED"
        },
        {
            "SubscriptionId": 588972,
            "SeatState": "ASSIGNED"
        }
    ],
    "DisplayName": "Joe Jane",
    "SubscriberState": "ACTIVE"
}
```

I want to find all users that have a SubscriptionId matching one of two values AND a SeatState that is not equal to ASSIGNED.  I am using the following find call.

```
GoodSubscriptions = [586102, 586104]
db = client.bsssubscriptions
Users = db.Users
BadSubscriptions = Users.find({'$and': [{'SubscriberState': 'ACTIVE'}, {'SubscriptionSet': {'$elemMatch': {{'SubscriptionId': {'$in': GoodSubscriptions}}, {'SeatState': {'$ne': 'ASSIGNED'}}}}}]})
```

and get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\BSS API\db query.py", line 24, in <module>
    BadVerse = Users.find({'SubscriptionSet': {'$elemMatch': {{'SubscriptionId': {'$in': GoodSubscriptions}}, {'SeatState': {'$ne': 'ASSIGNED'}}}}})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I have looked for this specific error and found many examples, but none were related to using a find with a records containing an array of dictionary pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many curly braces in the $elem subquery. Try this query:

```
{ 
  '$and': 
    [
      {'SubscriberState': 'ACTIVE'}, 
      {
        'SubscriptionSet': {
          '$elemMatch': {
            'SubscriptionId': {'$in': GoodSubscriptions}, 
            'SeatState': {'$ne': 'ASSIGNED'}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I actually think you want to use mongodb [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). Because with the $elemMatch if there is any element within embedded array which satisfies the condition then a whole document with a whole embedded array(despite whether another elements satisfy condition) will be returned.

Comment: Thank you!  I just found the extra curly brace and was going to post the answer, but you beat me to it.